# How do I install non-CRAN R packages onto AWS?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, devtools

I have recently, set up an AWS  accountand am in the process of uploading R packages I require

The process runs smoothly with CRAN packages using the command e.g.

```
sudo su ­ ­c "R ­e \"install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

For non-CRAN packages, I got some help from this source
https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/414 and tried

```
Rscript -e 'library(devtools); library(methods); install_github(commandArgs(TRUE))' "ramnathv/rCharts"
```

The zipped package (and others on  github ) download but then I get the error

```
'lib="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable .
```

although that is where the R packages were written to

Has anyone successfully achieved this process and could give me the solution
Tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need `sudo` to install to that directory. You could try

```
sudo Rscript -e 'library(devtools); library(methods); install_github(commandArgs(TRUE))' "ramnathv/rCharts"
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts.git
sudo R CMD INSTALL rCharts
```

Comment: The second option worked fine Thanks v much . For the uninitiated, I had to install git first  sudo apt-get install git